# Gradle Sync Failed to resolve: exifinterface - myhexaville smart image picker

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dependencies

[image]

I got this error when I used this dependency 'com.myhexaville:smart-image-picker:1.0.3'
When i commented this dependency, gradle synced successfully. 
Please suggest me a proper solution for this problem.

Comment: show your gradle code

Comment: Have you read this on GitHub Library page `This library is currently unsupported because I've switched my focus to Flutter and don't plan fixing any bugs any time soon`

Answer (score 0):

Add Google's Maven repository to your project's build.gradle file :

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }
```

If you are using android-studio 3.0 or above use this :

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    }
```